# Why does using requirejs 2 stop my backbone / jQuery mobile app working?

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, mobile, requirejs

I have a very simple proof of concept app built with jQuery Mobile, Backbone.js, and require.js.

I am using Backbone's router, and I have jQuery Mobile's routing disabled. It works perfectly.

I am using require.js 1.04.  However: when I use requirejs 2.1.14, then I can't seem to disable jQuery Mobile's routing, and hence Backbone's routing stops working. Can't figure it out.

The following code works if I remove jQuery mobile, but stops working if I put jQuery mobile back in. Similarly, it will work with Require.js 1.0.4, but not with require.js 2.1.14:

**index.html:**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="#posts/1">Click Here</a>
        <script data-main="main" src="require.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
require.config({
    paths : {
        backbone : 'libraries/backbone/backbone',
        underscore : 'libraries/underscore/underscore',
        jquery : 'libraries/jquery/jquery-1.7.1',
        jqm : 'libraries/jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile',
        router: 'router'
    },
    shim: {
        jqm: {
            exports: 'jqm',
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        underscore: {
            exports: 'underscore'
        },
        backbone: {
            exports: 'backbone',
            deps: ['jquery', 'underscore']
        }
    }
});

require(
    ['jquery', 'jqm', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'router'],
    function ($, $$, underscore, Backbone, router) {
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;

        router.init();
    });
```

**router.js**

```
define(['jquery', 'jqm', 'underscore', 'backbone'],
function($, $$, _, Backbone) {

    var init = function () {
            $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
            $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
            $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
            $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
            $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;

            var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
                routes: {
                    "posts/:id" : "getSomePost",
                    "*action": "defaultRoute"
                },
                getSomePost: function(id) {
                    alert( "Get post number " + id ); 
                },
                defaultRoute: function( actions ){
                    console.log('Action: ' + actions );
                }
            });

            // Instantiate the backbone router
            var app_router = new AppRouter();

            // Start Backbone history
            Backbone.history.start();


    };

    return { init : init };
});
```

*This problem is seriously baking my noodle!!*

When I load up the app, I see a link saying "Click here".  When the app uses requirejs-1.0.4 (or without jquery mobile) it works, I get an alert saying "get post number 1", and the URL looks like:

```
http://myapp.dev/src/#posts/1
```

but when using requirejs-2.1.14 and jQuery Mobile, I the URL quickly changes to this:

```
http://myapp.dev/src/posts/1
```

and nothing happens.

Help!

Comment: upgrade jQuery to 1.9 at least.

Comment: Are you able to link me to a zip of this? Can't be bothered to set it up ;)

Comment: Hey Omar, I updated to jQuery 1.11 - still no joy :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer to this problem.  The issue is the timing of jQuery Mobile configuration.  According to the jQuery Mobile docs:

> *Because the mobileinit event is triggered immediately, you'll need to*
>   *bind your event handler before jQuery Mobile is loaded*

So I rewrote main.js like so:

```
require.config({
    paths : {
        backbone : 'libraries/backbone/backbone',
        underscore : 'libraries/underscore/underscore',
        jquery : 'libraries/jquery/jquery-1.7.1',
        jqmconfig : 'jquerymobile.config',
        jqm : 'libraries/jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile',
        router: 'router'
    },
    shim: {
        jqm: {
            exports: 'jqm',
            deps: ['jquery', 'jqmconfig']
        },
        underscore: {
            exports: 'underscore'
        },
        backbone: {
            exports: 'backbone',
            deps: ['jquery', 'jqm', 'underscore']
        }
    }
});

require(
    ['jquery', 'backbone', 'jqmconfig', 'jqm', 'router'],
    function ($, Backbone, jqmconfig, $$, router) {
        router.init();
});
```

And added a new file called jquerymobile.config.js:

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
    $(document).on('mobileinit', function () {
        // Prevents all anchor click handling
        $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false

        // Disabling this will prevent jQuery Mobile from handling hash changes
        $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false

        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
    });
});
```

This code fires after jQuery has loaded, but **BEFORE** jQuery Mobile has loaded, which is the key!

For reference, this is the blog post that helped me figure it out:

http://www.justinmccandless.com/blog/Yeoman%2C+Requirejs%2C+jQuery+Mobile%2C+Backbone%2C+and+a+Lot+of+Config+Problems